# Backups utility - Is it possible to change to a new encryption password?

Tags: backup, encryption

I'm using the Ubuntu backup utility to save my home dir with my cloud provider. During set up I selected the option to encrypt the backup. I would now like to update to a stronger password but cannot see how to do this within the GUI:

[image]

When I check all the available settings in this gui there's none that I can see to update the encryption password. Is this possible?

Comment: Thanks @user68186! This link was helpful. I tried both gsettings and dconf-editor based on the link but did not find anything about password.

Comment: You are welcome. It was worth a shot. I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe it or not, this is remarkably easy ... so long as you don't mind creating a new full backup. Passwords are stored *per location* so, if you want to change your password, change the location where Deja Dupe saves your data.

Here's the full step-by-step:

1. Open Deja Dupe:
   [image: Open Deja Dupe]
2. Change the folder location in "Storage Location":
   [image: Deja Dupe - Storage Location]
3. Return to the "Overview" tab:
   [image: Deja Dupe - Overview]
4. Press "Back Up Now ..." and enter a new password:
   [image: Deja Dupe - Set Password]

In the event that you would like to update a previous backup (if you're backing up to a network device daily and a cloud device weekly/monthly), you can set the location to a previous setting and issue another on-demand backup. The password for all known locations are remembered for as long as the system installation exists.

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm using a cloud provider, and since it's already selected, there's no way to select the same provider again to create a new backup with that provider. There's no way to delete it either that I can see. Any ideas?

Comment: Well ... a "scorched earth" method would be to delete all of your past backups; particularly the signature files. Once all of the backups are gone, Deja Dup will have nothing to compare against and it will ask for a new password once you push the "Back Up Now..." button. The problem with this is that you will never be able to recover those previous backups ...

Comment: @DougFir can you login to your cloud provider (using the web interface, for example) and do things to the backup folder/files? If the backups are in one folder, rename the folder and create an empty folder by the same name. If they are not in a folder, put them in a folder. Then Ubuntu backup **should** create a new backup and ask for password again. I am just guessing, as I keep my backups in my network.

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion,  am going to try your second suggestion later today or tomorrow, will update you.

Comment: Your last suggestion seemed to do the trick - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no option to change the password is implemented in the Ubuntu backup utility. The utility is designed to be simple, so apparently this option was not deemed necessary by the developpers. To use another password, you indeed will need to set up a new backup.

If you have space on your cloud provider, it is preferred to set up the new backup before removing the old one. If you have not, then, if possible, try to have a second backup elsewhere. Otherwise, you will have only a single copy of the data during the time you recreate the backup. Although the chance that in that period something goes wrong with that single copy is probably very small, some risk always remains.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. "you indeed will need to set up a new backup." - there's no way in the UI that I can see to add a new back up. I appear to be stuck with my initial settings 'forever'